# Character encoding issues with Socket Connection

Tags: c#, sockets, character-encoding, tcpclient

I am sending data to a Socket and connection and retrieving some data. The data I am retrieving (which is an XML document) contains umlauts like ä,ü,ö,... but these are not correctly encoded, I only get ? or )))@ symbols instead of the umlaut.

Is there something incorrect how I retrieve the data ? The data is send back as ISO-8859-1 encoding.

My code:

```cs
public bool GetData()
    {
        try
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient("THEIP", 5004);

            NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();

            if (ns.CanWrite)
            {
                string text = this.xmlRequest;
                byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

                string sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(sendBytes);

                ns.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
            }

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

            int i = 0;

            if (ns.CanRead)
            {
                do
                {

                    byte[] recvBytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];

                    i = i + ns.Read(recvBytes, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);



                    string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBytes);

                    returnData = returnData.Substring(0, i);

                    this.xmlResponse = returnData;

                } while (ns.DataAvailable);
            }

            // got full data...
            bool status = this.ProcessXMLData();
            ns.Close();

            if (status)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }


        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            this.errorFlag = true;
            this.errorMessage = se.Message;
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure about the encode is being used is ISO-8859-1 then Instead of `Encoding.ASCII` use `Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")`

Comment: Will that make a difference?  Ascii encoding is typically used interchangeably with ISO-8859-1

Comment: Encoding.ASCII use 7 bit and Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1") use 8 bit